# Php Include : How to include many pages incremented?

Tags: php, arrays, auto-increment, php-include

i use this code :

```
<?php include("news/news05.php"); ?>
<?php include("news/news04.php"); ?>
<?php include("news/news03.php"); ?>
<?php include("news/news02.php"); ?>
<?php include("news/news01.php"); ?>
```

Is there a way to increment the inclusion automaticaly ? like for exemple if i put in my file a new page called "news06.php" ?

btw, is there a way to include many pages with a single line ?

Thank you for your help.

Benj

Comment: Try using a for loop or sth. similar and remember the last number, then increment.

Comment: are you use numeric value at the end of file name

Comment: Hi everybody, Sorry, i was checking my email waiting for answers and i got nothing, then i returned here to check and i see many comments and answers ! Thank you all very much i will study each of your answer and for sure i will be able to understand the process.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this solution:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    $fname = "news/news0{$i}.php";
    if (file_exists($fname)) {
        include($fname);
    }
}
?>
```

Just modify it closer for you needs...

Comment: you have a mistake `;` characters.

Comment: @dovy and where? Don't see any mistakes

Comment: Your result will likes this: `include(news/news01.php)include(news/news02.php)include(news/news03.php)include(news/news04.php)include(news/news05.php)include(news/news06.php)`

Answer (score 1):

When I have to do it, I use this:

```
$files = glob('news/news*[0-9].php', GLOB_BRACE);
natcasesort($files);
foreach ($files as $newsFile) {
    require_once($newsFile);
}
```

More info at [PHP: glob function manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php)

Comment: **Beware** this will select all files starting with news like `newsreader.php` , `news1.php`,etc  which you might not want to include

Comment: This will get any file that corresponds to news* (news_.php, news042.php, etc). You're free to use expressions to avoid unexpected files.

Comment: yeah correct, we cant confirm everybody has idea about that, so its better to inform the reader limitations or you should include the expressions to avoid unexpected files

Comment: Thank You, This anwser is very nice, but pages appears in a wrong order.

Comment: Take a look again. I've updated the answer and that should work fine =)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to write one include for include multi files

Put all the includes in one file and include that, or create loop for this

**But in my opinion keep it simple and write one line for each file**

Answer (score 0):

U can use an itteration for this

ex.

```
<?php
   for ($i=5;$i > 0; $i--) {
      include('news/news'.str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'.php');
   }
```

Comment: Don't you mean `str_pad()` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $files = 6;

    for($count = 1; $count <= $files; $count++)
        require_once"news/news" . sprintf("%02d", $count) . ".php";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    if(!@include("news/news".$i.".php")) {
       break;
    } else {
       include("news/news".$i.".php");
    }
}
```

Something like this

Comment: I do not like this solution as the other, but maybe you want to replace the `continue;` with `break;`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, let's say you have news10 , and you still want pages with 0-based like news01 for single digit numbers (less than 10), so you can add this simple if condition to achieve your need:

```
<?php
for ($i=10;$i > 0;$i--){
    if ($i <10)
       $i = "0$i";
    include("news/news$i.php");
}
?>
```

You can use for loop like this:

```
<?php
for ($i=6;$i > 0;$i--){
    include("news/news0$i.php");
}
?>
```

the index is fixed here, you can read it from a db or an xml file, if you want to maintain the value from outside the script.

Comment: Didn't know that variables gets parsed in single quotes ?

Comment: sry my bad, i tried echo-ing the include before posting here.

Comment: Thank you very much Aram, This answer is nice, but what if i call my file "news10.php" ?